# Error when adding Excel to POST request in Karate

Tags: karate

I created this request:

```
Scenario: import-items
* def req = __arg.request
* def authHeader = call read('karate-auth.js') req.auth
* def headers = karate.merge(req.headers || {}, authHeader || {})
Given path '/api/v1/excel/snapshot/import-items'
And multipart file fileName = {read: 'classpath: excelFiles/excel.xlsx', fileName: 'excel.xlsx', contentType: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'}
And headers headers
When method POST
```

And Karate is giving me this error:

```
import-items.feature:23 - could not find or read file: classpath: excelFiles/excel.xlsx
```

I add here the cUrl request that it's working:

```
curl --location --request POST 'myUrl/api/v1/excel/snapshot/import-items' \
--header 'Authorization: *************************' \
--header 'Cookie: ****************' \
--form 'fileName=@"/absolutePath/excelFiles/excel.xlsx"'
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message is pretty clear, so looks like you have got the `classpath:` wrong, so read the docs: https://github.com/intuit/karate#reading-files

You can also try with:

```
read: 'file:/absolutePath/excelFiles/excel.xlsx'
```

Otherwise, this works for me and others. Follow this process if still stuck: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: But the path is correct, that's why I don't understand that error message.
I have tried with file: and it's working but with absolute path only, and I need it to be relative, any idea?

Comment: if it is "side-by-side" with the feature file, you don't need any prefix. read the docs. if still stuck who knows it may be a bug :| so follow the process in the link